# jQuery array not working - only first item of array works?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is the code that I currently have:

```
<script>
var zips = ['30068', '90120','30033'];
$(function(){
  $('input[name=zip]').change(function(){
    var currentVal = $(this).val(); 
    if(!$.inArray(currentVal, zips)){
       $('.checkout_button').prop('disabled',true);
    } else {
       $('.checkout_button').prop('disabled',false);
      }
    });
});
</script>
```

I want it so that when the user types in their zip code it sees if we support their service or not. This works currently but only works with 
**30068**. By this, I mean that if I type in **90120** it runs the wrong response unlike **30068**. Basically, only the first item of the array correctly works? Why is this?

> If You Believe This Is A Duplicate Please Explain So I Can Change My Answer.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inArray/

Comment: should be `if($.inArray(currentVal, zips) === -1){`, as it does not return a boolean but an index.

Comment: @trincot I changed it to what you said and it has not worked.

Comment: Post a [mcve] please which would include the HTML

Comment: I would rather use keyup, but, basically - code should work: https://jsfiddle.net/qyn2rdot/